# How can I get people to put their money where their mouth is?

Tags: society, technology, economy, alternate-history

When individuals cede their power for effective choice to involuntary institutions, as soon as there's an uncoupling between what the institutions are aiming at and the interests of people, which do you think goes down the drain? And it's a matter of when, not if.

**Goal:** The prevailing norms should be such that people invest their money where they themselves consider ethical, and avoid contact with bad currency. There should be enough transparency in the chain of financial transactions that the extent to which an investment is socially productive or destructive is publicly knowable with reasonable accuracy. People must be able to *quantify* 'guilt by (fiscal) association' with reasonable accuracy.

**Task: What's the most efficient way to reach the goal above?**

**Requirements:**

- Applies to the whole world.
- **No introduction of changes after 1999 or before 1700.**
- You *aren't* starting from scratch. Please specify when, where and by whom your suggested changes would be introduced, and why such norms would take over incompatible contemporary ones around the world.
- Technology, social tools or any combination thereof are allowed.
- Already existing tools are preferred. Strictly no technology less mature than the [demonstration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technology_readiness_level) stage as of 1999.
- States, governments, political bodies or legislative bodies must not have any hand in implementing these changes.
- No warfare as a side effect.

There's been a multitude of comments wildly misinterpreting the question. Yes, individuals' ideas as to what is 'ethical' are massively disparate, and this must be respected; the goal is just to have people express these values economically to strengthen competition in the human moral ecosystem.

Comment: (1) Financial investments by "authorities in any country" are called sovereign investment funds are *are* subject to scrutiny. (2) What would be socially productive for comrade Stalin may not necessarily be considered socially productive by other people. Do you really believe that doubling the tonnes of steel per head is all that important? (3) By and large, most countries maintain registries of ownership of shares in public companies. In general it is perfectly possible to find out that, for example, the popular radio station RTL2 is owned by the RTL Group which is owned by Bertelsmann.

Comment: (1) Removed. (2) This isn't really relevant. The economic effectiveness of a person with communist leanings would be limited by a large number of people with an interest in preventing dangerous behaviour. Further, such a person would still be useful in other ways and could get along with others provided he had no direct bad effect on them. Even if your fears were more founded, they aren't exactly within the scope of the question. (3) Sure, but are people actively reading these registries, using their knowledge etc?

Comment: If it wasn't clear -- what may be socially productive for comrade Subdermatoglyphic may not necessarily be considered socially productive by other people. And yes, investors are very actively reading those registries. Or do you think that Mr. Warren Buffett places his money randomly? You may disagree with Mr. Buffett about the best placement of his money, or you may even disagree with his criteria for evaluating best, but this is called *freedom*. Forcing all the people to have a single common opinion on the best investments is what comrade Stalin did.

Comment: I'm not asking for homogeneity of opinion; in fact, I want the opposite. As the question states, I want people to decide where to invest based on their own values.

Comment: Then I am very confused. How do you think that people decide where to invest, if not based on their own values? As far as I know nobody is forcing anybody to put their money where they don't want to.

Comment: Not everything is because of actual agents. Bad incentives and wrong information flows might do it.

Comment: It sounds like you want people to have different values, not put their money where their values are. Because they already do and it's how we got the current mess in the first place.

Comment: @Erik I'm not so sure about that. Is blindly consuming branded goods and services related to ethics? Is a large proportion of financial decisions based on transparent information and personal responsibility? Do you think millions of people let their money go to oil and weapons industries because their ethical values say so?

Comment: @subdermatoglyphic no, they do because their values tell them quick money and ignorance are better than hard choices and information.

Comment: I don't think that's a viable interpretation of all such behaviour. Mostly they don’t have the time, knowledge or ability to do certain things on their own.

Comment: *"[The Soviet man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Soviet_man) was to be selfless, learned, healthy, muscular, and enthusiastic in spreading the socialist Revolution. [...] He was not driven by crude impulses of nature but by conscious self-mastery."* In Leon Trotsky's words: *"man will make it his purpose to master his own feelings, to raise his instincts to the heights of consciousness, to make them transparent, to extend the wires of his will into hidden recesses, and thereby to raise himself to a new plane, to create a higher social biologic type, or, if you please, a superman."*

Comment: The Soviet communists thought man was perfectible. This is wrong and was not presupposed in the question. Note: they didn't even know how to achieve the type of 'new man' described in your quotations.

Comment: `they didn't even know how to achieve the type of 'new man' described in your quotations.` Heh, even most of the people today don't know how to make ethical choices, nor they do care or even want to. And it just seems to me that you are asking WB how to arrange a governance system that will force people to give more than a damn about ethics (which is a sign that even you don't know how to convince them). Point: I wouldn't be so fast to see the speck in your soviet communist bro... err... comrade, I mean. :grin:

Comment: So exactly how does your proposal differ from the current state of affairs?  What you may not fully understand is that many people have ideas about what's "ethical" or "socially productive" that differ from yours.

Comment: The best way to get people to put their money where their mouth is? Make the money taste good.

Comment: @Jedediah ummm... on the same line, I'm already putting money where my mouth is every time I pay a visit to my dentist. It ain't cheap, that visit! It follows that any change in the lifestyle that increases the frequency of dentist visits will do. So, how about in addition to making money taste good, we make them tough? Or sweet and acidic? I know! Central banks should start printing sour rock candy!!!

Comment: The addition of the final paragraph doesn't make the question as a whole any more likely to produce non-opinion-based (ie. [non-subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)) answers. You would need to narrow the scope greatly to give us an [answerable question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 0):

### Customers are shareholders, not just giving money to a Company but Owning the Company as they obtain goods and services

If the rules of the very first corporations are changed to suit an investment into the company in lieu of providing money to the company in return for goods and services, this could have profound effects.

Companies currently raise capital in various ways, usually by investors or funds that provide the company cash to operate. *The 'customer' of a current company is actually the shareholders, not the real 'customers'*. However, **what if the accepted source of capital were the real customers themselves?** And it became the norm for customers to receive shares in return for their custom, which then rewards them in time with profits and dividends.

This could be achieved in 1700 when the large Dutch East India and Hudson Bay companies formed at the start of the era of Merchantism. If *customers who purchase the teas (or spices) were actually purchasing ownership shares, and obtain tea upon voyage return,* this forms the precedence required for rules and regulations to set up ensuring this is the default way a company is established.

What this would do is:

- Companies would have a strong incentive to service their customers better, who would be the actual investors as well, because the owners decide how they want to be treated.
- People are directly affected by who they are investing in, meaning they have a direct interest and are affected by the services and goods provided by the company. They are less likely to want to provide money to a 'bad company' as they will suffer the effects themselves.
- Companies are owned by their customers and governance of the company would be decided primarily by their own customers. Profit is not the only consideration, but quality and suitability of product.
- Unethical practices, unhealthy foods, damaging products (such as weapons or harmful substances) would be consumed by the purchaser who either:

  1. Decides not to purchase because it would not be good for them. The company then would cease to exist or struggle to do so.
  2. The company has an incentive to retain the customer, who is an owner and decision maker, and thus changes the product to better increase the lifespan of the customer/owner or the quality of life.

This is made easier by technology as soon you would have thousands of owners, so shares need to translate to governance (which is the case now), and need to be done so using share classification. There are likely many other changes that would need to flow on as well, for instance dealing with inheritance, trading of shares and so on, but perhaps this simple shift in ways companies are formed could assist you.

Comment: I'm not certain that I understand how this works. Let's take a simple example. We have here in Bucharest a company called Spicul which makes bread, sells about 100,000 loaves per day, and it has been doing it for some 70 years. If buying a loaf of bread implied buying a (tiny) piece of the company, we would have to hire a small army of public employees just to keep track of the shareholders... And instead of a few seconds, buying that loaf of bread would take a quater of an hour or more -- show the identity papers, get a share certificate... And the bread sellers would be notaries public...

Comment: @AlexP [Bearer shares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bearer_instrument#Bearer_shares) printed on the loafs :grin: This way, the consumer realizes that economy is not an end in itself but a mean to an end (making his life possible). Indeed, the consumer has now the choice in preserving the bread until it "matures" (and die of hunger) or eat his shares and make the shares contribute towards his life (thus making a shit from the shares). Oooops, jesting initially ... but perhaps there is something into this? :grin:

Comment: This seems like it would do weird things to prices. If I have a loaf of bread and it's worth 5 dollars, you pay 5 dollars and you get bread, that's a fair deal. You don't get bread *and $5 worth of my company*; if I agreed to that I'd be out money for no gain.